# Pandas apply but only for rows where a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I would like to use Pandas `df.apply` but only for certain rows

As an example, I want to do something like this, but my actual issue is a little more complicated:

```
import pandas as pd
import math
z = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0],'b':[6.0,0,5.0,0,1.0]})
z.where(z['b'] != 0, z['a'] / z['b'].apply(lambda l: math.log(l)), 0)
```

What I want in this example is the value in 'a' divided by the log of the value in 'b' for each row, and for rows where 'b' is 0, I simply want to return 0.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The other answers are excellent, but I thought I'd add one other approach that can be faster in some circumstances – using broadcasting and masking to achieve the same result:

```
import numpy as np

mask = (z['b'] != 0)
z_valid = z[mask]

z['c'] = 0
z.loc[mask, 'c'] = z_valid['a'] / np.log(z_valid['b'])
```

Especially with very large dataframes, this approach will generally be faster than solutions based on `apply()`.

Comment: So this mask masks out the values that you don't want. In this case, you are "selecting" those `z` values that are not zero. Is that correct?

Comment: It's a boolean mask that selects just the nonzero values. You can read more here: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.02-data-indexing-and-selection.html

Comment: What if we need to apply a function to a large dataframe? Could we do something like `z.loc[mask, 'c'] = func(z_valid['a'], z_valid['b']` ?

Comment: For this approach, does the `mask` selection runs twice? For example, in `z[mask]` and in `z.loc[mask, 'c']`

Comment: you can use this answer like a sql update with a where clause: update table set table.c = table.a / table.b where table.b is not null. Except you define the "where" clause first.

Answer (score 59):

You can just use an if statement in a lambda function.

```
z['c'] = z.apply(lambda row: 0 if row['b'] in (0,1) else row['a'] / math.log(row['b']), axis=1)
```

I also excluded 1, because log(1) is zero.

Output:

```
   a  b         c
0  4  6  2.232443
1  5  0  0.000000
2  6  5  3.728010
3  7  0  0.000000
4  8  1  0.000000
```

Comment: I know I'm late to the game here, but why do you need to specify axis =1?  Isn't it specified in the syntax?  and why axis=1 not 0?

Comment: @Windstorm1981 see "axis": https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: `axis = 1`  needs to be a parameter of the `apply()` function, not of `lambda`. You might need extra brackets around your `lambda` function.

Answer (score 18):

Hope this helps. It is easy and readable

```
df['c']=df['b'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x ==0 else math.log(x))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a lambda with a conditional to return 0 if the input value is 0 and skip the whole `where` clause:

```
z['c'] = z.apply(lambda x: math.log(x.b) if x.b > 0 else 0, axis=1)
```

You also have to assign the results to a new column (`z['c']`).

Answer (score 1):

Use [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which divides `a` by the log of the value in `b` if the condition is met and returns 0 otherwise:

```
import numpy as np
z['c'] = np.where(z['b'] != 0, z['a'] / np.log(z['b']), 0)
```

Output:

```
     a    b         c
0  4.0  6.0  2.232443
1  5.0  0.0  0.000000
2  6.0  5.0  3.728010
3  7.0  0.0  0.000000
4  8.0  1.0       inf
```