# Pandas - How to apply calculation based on another row (which may change during calculation...)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write - using xlwings as an enabler - a Gantt chart tool with an XLS front end. I have it working well currently but am missing a 'task link' feature.

Currently, a table in Excel is read in to Python using xlwings and converted to a dataframe where some other calculations are done. I have in this table/DF the following columns that would make up the linked-date calc:

- **Link ID**: each item in the table has a unique ID; the user selects the ID they want to link a tasks to
- **Date**: The date the item starts on
- **Length**: The length of the task
- **Offset**: An additional offset to apply to the task link

Where I am getting stuck is that in order to calculate the **Date** for a task linked to another task, I need to get the date and length of the task of the ID that the user has given.

I have used this post - [Pandas apply but only for rows where a condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769860/pandas-apply-but-only-for-rows-where-a-condition-is-met) - which overall works well, but where it falls down is that if you have a task linked to another task that is also linked, it doesn't seem to update the date correctly; I am assuming because it is effectively volatile when it does the calcs.

I almost certainly could use `df.iterrows()` but would like to try and find a more elegant solution. Some sample code is below (not from my actual application, but trying to do the same thing) that is based on the post above to try and show where I have got so far:

(Edit: more information plus expected outcomes added below)

Example input dataframe is:

| ID (index) | Link | Date | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | None | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | None | 11 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | None | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | None | 1 |
| 5 | None | 14 | 1 |

The idea is that ID 3 is to be linked to ID 2, and that ID 4 is to be linked to ID 3. Therefore, the resulting dataframe should be as below, where the 'Date' (I am just using an integer here for ease) is calculated by (Date of linked item + Length of linked item):

| ID (index) | Link | Date | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | None | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | None | 11 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 12 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 13 | 1 |
| 5 | None | 14 | 1 |

First the 'setup'code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a DataFrame with some sample data
# None in 'Link' shows where the user has chosen not to link the task to another
data_dict = dict(
    UUID= [1,2,3,4,5],
    Link= [None, None, 2, 3, None],
    Date= [10,11,None,None,14],
    Length= [1,1,1,1,1]
)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
df = df.set_index('UUID')

mask = (pd.notna(df['Link']))
```

Then the code to apply the linked date calculation based on the mask defined above - this is the part that I have either written incorrectly or is not doing what I expect it to:

```py
df.loc[mask, 'Date'] = df.loc[df.loc[mask, 'Link']]['Date'] + df.loc[df.loc[mask, 'Link']]['Length']
```

The actual resulting dataframe from the above code is:

| ID (index) | Link | Date | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | None | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | None | 11 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | None | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | None | 1 |
| 5 | None | 14 | 1 |

Which is exactly the same as the input...

Isolating part of that final block of code and running it (after re-running the 'setup' code):

```py
df.loc[df.loc[mask, 'Link']]['Date'] + df.loc[df.loc[mask, 'Link']]['Length']
```

The return is:

```
ID
2.0    12.0
3.0    NaN
dtype: float64
```

This shows that it is performing the (date + length) sum correctly for ID2 (which forms the date for ID3) but is then not calculating it for ID3 which, to me, implies that the value for ID2 (12.0) is not 'fixed' before the calculation for ID3 takes place and so it cannot calculate it properly.

I hope the additional information has explained this a bit more clearly.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "if you have a task linked to another task that is also linked, it doesn't seem to update the date correctly;".  You seem to think it is because the date is volatile, yet once you have grabbed the date, the date you are working with is no longer volatile?

Comment: Yes, of course. This might be my not fully understanding how Pandas actually applies these calculations.

Comment: (Sorry, hit enter by mistake...)

If I were doing this with an iteration (e.g. `df.iterrows()`) then, as you say, the previous date would already be calculated so job done. It just feels like my approach above - to make it more elegant - might not run the calcs in quite the same way and so a date is not calculated correctly.

Effectively, if Task C is linked to Task B which is linked to Task A, then the date calculation for Task C relies on Task B's being performed first, based on the date of Task A.

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.