# Apply conditional statement to specific rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, input

I have a dataset where I would like a certain statement to only be applied to specific rows in my dataset. I would like this to only be applied to rows that contain [type] == 'aa', and apply second statement for rows that contain [type] == 'bb'

**Data**

```
location    type    mig1        de          mig2        re
ny          aa      8/1/2021    10/1/2021   1/1/2022    2/1/2022
ny          aa      8/1/2021    10/1/2021   1/1/2022    2/1/2022
ca          aa      8/1/2021    10/1/2021   1/1/2022    2/1/2022
tx          bb      9/1/2021    11/1/2021   2/1/2022    3/1/2022
```

**Desired**

```
 #Date 8/1/2022 is input, which yields:

    location    type    mig1        de          mig2        re
    ny          aa      03/1/2022   05/1/2022   8/1/2022    7/1/2022
    ny          aa      03/1/2022   05/1/2022   8/1/2022    7/1/2022
    ca          aa      03/1/2022   05/1/2022   8/1/2022    7/1/2022
    tx          bb      03/1/2021   11/1/2021   08/1/2022   3/1/2022



Logic - we see that the shift applies to all columns when the type == aa
        when the type value == bb, a different statement is applied
```

**Doing**

#takes input value

```
datevalue = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter shift: "))
```

#shifts dates from the datevalue input - However I would like **d** variable to only be applied to
the rows that contain [type] == 'aa'

#apply **e** variable to rows that contain [type] = 'bb'

```
d = {
    'mig1': pd.DateOffset(months=5),
    'de': pd.DateOffset(months=3),
    're': pd.DateOffset(months=1),
}

e = {
        'mig1': pd.DateOffset(months=5),
        
    }


s = pd.Series(d).rsub(datevalue)
df.assign(**{**s, 'mig2': datevalue})
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Sounds a lot like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769860/pandas-apply-but-only-for-rows-where-a-condition-is-met).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
datevalue = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter shift: "), dayfirst=False)  # 08/01/2022

new_values = pd.Series(d).rsub(datevalue) \
                         .append(pd.Series({'mig2': datevalue})) \
                         .dt.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y')
df.update(pd.DataFrame([new_values], index=df[df['type'] == 'aa'].index))

# do the same for type='bb' and 'e' dict
new_values = pd.Series(e).rsub(datevalue) \
                         .append(pd.Series({'mig2': datevalue})) \
                         .dt.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y')
df.update(pd.DataFrame([new_values], index=df[df['type'] == 'bb'].index))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  location type      mig1         de      mig2        re
0       ny   aa  3/1/2022   5/1/2022  8/1/2022  7/1/2022
1       ny   aa  3/1/2022   5/1/2022  8/1/2022  7/1/2022
2       ca   aa  3/1/2022   5/1/2022  8/1/2022  7/1/2022
3       tx   bb  3/1/2022  11/1/2021  8/1/2022  3/1/2022
```

Comment: Ok will try- how did you get the final output? Did you concatenate the ‘d’ and ‘e’ output?

Comment: I reused the last two lines. I just changed `'aa'` by `'bb'` and `d` by `e`.

Comment: I understood now `mig2` is `datevalue`.

Comment: Ok and mig2 should be 8/1/2022 because mig2 is that input.

Comment: Yes but bb has and exception. For ‘bb’ only mig1 and mig2 are updated. de and re stay the same and are untouched

Comment: Please look at desired output. If == bb, de and re are unchanged

Comment: As I said, it's not a problem for type `bb`. Your dict `e` does not contain `de` and `re` so the values are not updated.

Comment: Ok I will check this - for bb, I only want mig1 and mig2 to be updated. De and re should remain the same.

Comment: Thank you I will try this

Comment: Did you have time to try my answer? I also answered to your (similar) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70513955/15239951)

Comment: Will try- I marked other soln correct as I see how the output will be derived thank you. I like your explanation as well

Comment: Are these ‘ \ ‘ apart of the statement? If so, what is their function? Thanks

Comment: It's to avoid horizontal scrollbar. You can remove them to reformat the code on one line.

Comment: Thanks for your support :) Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you I will build off of you your solution and increase my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

```
#Coerce dates to datetime
df1=df1.set_index(['location','type']).apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,format='%d/%m/%Y'))

#Set non dates as index, slice level two and impose the datetifference
df1.loc[ ( slice(None), 'aa' ),  : ]=df1.loc[ ( slice(None), 'aa' ),  : ]-pd.to_timedelta(5, unit='d')


                  mig1         de       mig2         re
location type                                            
ny       aa   2021-01-03 2021-01-05 2021-12-27 2021-12-28
         aa   2021-01-03 2021-01-05 2021-12-27 2021-12-28
ca       aa   2021-01-03 2021-01-05 2021-12-27 2021-12-28
tx       bb   2021-01-09 2021-01-11 2022-01-02 2022-01-03
```

Comment: hi- was wondering if input statement is used?  - needing to input a specific date

Comment: Not sure I understood your question. Input what date and how?

Comment: Ok. I am using input() function to input the date : 8/01/2022-  whenever a specific date is entered the dates will shift. Only wish to apply to certain rows though

Comment: possible but quite a complicated model especially with the multiple date fields. Will try figure it out

Comment: Ah ok I have the conditionals but trying to incorporate in the above script

Comment: As I figure that out, will leave my answer just in case someone needs to use slice :-)

Comment: Sure of course thank you