# Utilize Python Input() to apply conditionals on a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, input

I have a dataset where, whenever a date value in the `mig2` column is entered into the input() prompt, **mig1, de** and **re**
values will be updated according to these rules:

```
   mig1 is 5 months from the date entered in the input() prompt
   de   is 3 months from the date entered in the input() prompt
   re   is 1 month from the date entered in the input() prompt
   Where [type] column values == 'aa'
```

**The only data that is changing are the **dates**, which are essentially getting shifted based upon the user input.**

**Data**

```
location    type    mig1        de          mig2        re
ny          aa      8/1/2021    10/1/2021   1/1/2022    2/1/2022
ny          aa      8/1/2021    10/1/2021   1/1/2022    2/1/2022
ca          aa      8/1/2021    10/1/2021   1/1/2022    2/1/2022
tx          bb      9/1/2021    11/1/2021   2/1/2022    3/1/2022
```

**Desired**

```
 #Date 8/1/2022 is input, which yields:

    location    type    mig1        de          mig2        re
    ny          aa      03/1/2022   05/1/2022   8/1/2022    7/1/2022
    ny          aa      03/1/2022   05/1/2022   8/1/2022    7/1/2022
    ca          aa      03/1/2022   05/1/2022   8/1/2022    7/1/2022
    tx          bb      03/1/2021   11/1/2021   08/1/2022   3/1/2022
```

Input prompt will ask user which date value they wish to input.
**User inputs the date '8/1/2021'**, **which updates the remaining column date values.** based on rules above.

**Doing**

```
datevalue = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter shift: "))


d = {
    'mig1': pd.DateOffset(months=5),
    'de': pd.DateOffset(months=3),
    're': pd.DateOffset(months=1),
}

   e = {
        'mig1': pd.DateOffset(months=5),
        
    }


s = pd.Series(d).rsub(datevalue)
s1 = pd.Series(e).rsub(datevalue)
df.assign(**{**s,s1, 'mig2': datevalue})


Run d if type == 'aa'
Run e if type = 'bb'
```

Any suggestion is appreciated - Above script works well, but looking for suggestion on incorporating the conditionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than to use a conditional statement, it's probably better to build a dataframe to update yours. For that, I slightly modified your input:

```
data = {
    'aa': {'mig1': pd.DateOffset(months=5),
           'de': pd.DateOffset(months=3),
           're': pd.DateOffset(months=1),
           'mig2': pd.DateOffset(0)},
    'bb': {'mig1': pd.DateOffset(months=5),
           'mig2': pd.DateOffset(0)}
}
```

Now, compute the new values with `datevalue`, format date to be merged with the original dataframe and create the new dataframe:

```
data = {typ: {col: (datevalue - offset).strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y')
                 for col, offset in cols.items()}
           for typ, cols in data.items()}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data).T.loc[df['type']].set_index(df.index)
print(df1)

# Output
  type      mig1        de        re      mig2
0   aa  3/1/2022  5/1/2022  7/1/2022  8/1/2022
1   aa  3/1/2022  5/1/2022  7/1/2022  8/1/2022
2   aa  3/1/2022  5/1/2022  7/1/2022  8/1/2022
3   bb  3/1/2022       NaN       NaN  8/1/2022
```

Finally update your dataframe:

```
df.update(df1)
print(df)

# Output
  location type      mig1         de      mig2        re
0       ny   aa  3/1/2022   5/1/2022  8/1/2022  7/1/2022
1       ny   aa  3/1/2022   5/1/2022  8/1/2022  7/1/2022
2       ca   aa  3/1/2022   5/1/2022  8/1/2022  7/1/2022
3       tx   bb  3/1/2022  11/1/2021  8/1/2022  3/1/2022
```

Comment: Ok this also utilizes the date value input() right? Thank you

Comment: Yes I used `datevalue = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter shift: "))`

Comment: Could you tell me why a conditional is not the best solution? Is for updating purposes? thank you

Comment: datevalue - off  Is the off short for offset? Thanks

Comment: If you have 10, 100, 1000 types... Maybe you have only 2 but you have to copy/paste the code, so twice as likely to make a mistake :)

Comment: I replaced `off` with `offset`.

Comment: Essentially you are creating a ‘for’ loop it looks like for the first part?

Comment: Yes to update values inside the dictionary. After that, there is only one update operation.

Comment: Ok also why rename axis? And reset index? I believe the ‘loc’ is grouping or subsetting?

Comment: Now that I think about it, it could be easier. Check my update.

Comment: No that’s fine I was just wondering

Comment: The .T is the transposition?

Comment: Right a shortcut for `transpose()`. Here `pd.DataFrame(data).T` is equivalent to `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')`

Comment: Also I see both are named ‘data’ this should still work? (The dict and for loop statement have same variable name)

Comment: Yes I override the variable, it's not a problem because the first dict is now useless after update the values.

Comment: is it possible to change input to an integer vs the date like my latest post? Thanks