# How to unify units?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a **python.new** who need some help in the following question:

I got a dataframe like this.

df:

| index | height | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 181.5 | cm |
| 1 | 72.5 | inches |
| 2 | 168.0 | cm |
| 3 | NaN | NaN |
| .. | .. | .. |

...2000+rows

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[181.5,'cm'],
               [72.5,'inches'],
               [168.0,'cm'],
               ['NaN','NaN']],
         columns = ['height','unit'],
         index=[1,2,3,4])
```

I want to unify the `unit` to "cm", and make corresponding changes to `height`, and keep the 'NaN's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary to map conversion factors and use indexing to update the values/units:

```
# ensure real NaNs:
df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)

# set up dictionary of conversion factors
d = {'cm': 1, 'inches': 2.54}

# map converted heights
df['height'] = df['height'].mul(df['unit'].map(d))
# update units
df.loc[df['unit'].isin(d), 'unit'] = 'cm'
```

output:

```
   height unit
1  181.50   cm
2  184.15   cm
3  168.00   cm
4     NaN  NaN
```

###### handling unknown units

if you want to handle the case of values for which units are unknown and leave them unchanged, use `map(lambda x: d.get(x, 1))` instead of `map`

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769860/pandas-apply-but-only-for-rows-where-a-condition-is-met) solution using a mask:

```py
mask = (df['unit'] == 'inches')
df_inches = df[mask]
df.loc[mask, 'height'] = df_inches['height'] * 2.54
df.loc[mask, 'unit'] = 'cm'

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   height unit
1   181.5   cm
2  184.15   cm
3   168.0   cm
4     NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and professional answer！